# Switching to AMD ryzen 5900x or 5950x. Any stability problem with 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, cpu, amd-processor, cpufreq, amd-ryzen

I only run codes (C, Python) on my desktop which I am thinking of upgrading, either to AMD ryzen 5900x or to 5950x. I will be using ubuntu 20.04 LTS (only, no windows). Does anyone have any experience of running ubuntu on either of these CPU? Are there stability issues, such as kernel issues, problem while waking up from sleep mode, max frequency being low, wifi problem etc?

N.B. I am asking this because my laptop (legion 5) with R9 4800H is still facing a lot of stability issues (related to CPU) on ubuntu 20.04 LTS!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do not support hardware recommendations. If there are stability problems those are bugs and need to be treated as such. Mind that I would avoid amd anyways

Comment: Okay, I change the question which now focuses on any know issues with the hardware on ubuntu.